# Check input value against a constant and use it to update state and className on an element in React

Tags: react-native, syntax, jsx, setstate, conditional-operator

This is my first time trying to code my own React app so please bear with me! I'm really struggling with the syntax and would appreciate your expertise. The code at the bottom doesn't work but I hope it helps to illustrate what I'm trying to do. Also please let me know if you believe there is a better way to structure this. Thank you in advance!

My objective is to:

1. Upon clicking the Submit button, the function `checkPass` compares the input value `pass` to the constant `passcode`.
2. If `pass` matches `passcode`, the state of `transferReveal` is updated accordingly with the value `'show'` (or `'hide'` if no match).
3. The element `TransferBox` is then rendered according to its class, depending on the the state of `transferReveal` —basically I would like the visibility of this element to toggle depending whether the user inputs the correct key.

Full code from `App.js` below:

```js
import './App.css';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      transferReveal: 'hide'
    };
  };

  passcode = "24";

  checkPass = () => {
    this.setState((pass, passcode) => ({
      pass === passcode ? {transferReveal: 'show'} : {transferReveal: 'hide'}
    }));
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>
          <input
            placeholder="Input private key.."
            type="password"
            value={pass}
          />
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
            onClick={this.checkPass}
          />
        </form>
        //Check using state as className
        <TransferBox className={`transferReveal`} />
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-cloud-hgke6?file=/src/App.js:0-1045

Comment: @sidverma Thank you so much for your reply! I can see the form rendering correctly. I have a question about the state. When I check this in the console, it still says 'hide' after I enter the code and hit submit. Does this have something to do with React batching state calls?